# Sequence of chars with numerical parts

Tags: c++

I am using something like `sprintf(base_name,"%d.pgm", frame_number);` and passing `frame_number` as an integer (i.e. 1, 2, 3, ...10, 11 etc.) to generate the following sequence of image names:

```
1.pgm, 2.pgm, 3.pgm....10.pgm, 11.pgm etc.
```

How can I change this to output the following:

```
0001.pgm, 0002.pgm, 0003.pgm....0010.pgm, 0011.pgm etc.
```

I am using this to load images from a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sprintf(base_name, "%04d.pgm", frame_number);` I believe is what you're looking for.

`%04d` means...

`%d` is a place holder for an `int`.
`0` indicates leading zeros.
`4` indicates total field width minimum of 4 characters wide (and in this case, extra spaces are filled with your leading zeros).

These are called `format specifiers` and they come from `C`, so they're universal across all `C-based` languages as far as I know.  If you have questions similar to this in the future, just search for `C printf format specifiers` or something, and you'll probably get what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Use `%04d`.

0 means add 0 at the start, 4 .means how many min digits